# Can Oozie HDFS action use file patterns or glob?

Tags: oozie

Can I use wildcards (e.g. *) or file patterns (e.g. {}) in Oozie move actions?

I am trying to move the results of my job into archiving directory.

State of the directory structure:

```
output
 - 201304
 - 201305
archive
 - 201303
```

My action:

```
<fs name="archive-files">
    <move source="hdfs://namenode/output/{201304,201305}"
          target="hdfs://namenode/archive" />
    <ok to="next"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</fs>
```

resulting error:

```
FS006: move, source path [hdfs://namenode/output/{201304,201305}] does not exist
```

Is there an easy way to move more than one file in a glob or bash like syntax?  Looking to do something similar to this hadoop command:

```
hadoop fs -mv hdfs://namenode/output/{201304,201305} hdfs://namenode/archive
```

Am I missing something?  The hadoop fs command accepts glob.  Does Oozie?

Answer (score 1):

Oozie HDFS action has quite limited functionality, which is fully described in [functional specification](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.4_Fs_HDFS_action). To do something more complicated you can use [Shell action](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/DG_ShellActionExtension.html). It allows to run arbitrary shell commands as part of workflow, e.g. `hadoop fs` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

No - from my experience it doesn't look like it works.

FS006: move, source path [hdfs://nodename:8020/projects/blah/201*.gz] does not exist

Answer (score -1):

In workflow.xml use this:

```
    <action name="Movefiles">
    <fs>
    <move source='${SourcePath}' target='${DestinationPath}'/>
    </fs>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
   </action>
```

and in job.properties write:

SourcePath=output/*/

DestinationPath=archive